# Fstab not automatically mounting SMB storage?

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

Is there something wrong with my mounting?

```
//192.168.1.150/Drew /media/Cloud cifs auto,credentials=/home/drew/.credentials/smb,_netdev,uid=drew,gid=drew,rw 0 0
```

When I run `sudo mount -a` the drive is mounted, no issues. But, the drive will not automatically mount when the system boots up?

```
uname -a
Linux drew-desktop 4.14.24-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 4 21:28:02 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

pacman -Q | grep cifs
cifs-utils 6.7-2

ls -l /media | grep Cloud
drwxr-xr-x  2 drew drew    0 Mar  9 17:32 Cloud
```

Comment: Did you enable the service that performs mounting of network filesystems?

Comment: I do not remember doing so. What is the name of the service that does that?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba#Automatic_mounting

Comment: Thanks, I enabled the service and did logged off/in to test it. That seems to have been my issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to enable the service that automounts network drives as @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said. The details are [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba#Automatic_mounting).

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting your success!  <del>The detailed effect of this command is detailed at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/</del>  This sounds like it was a bug in your original setup.  Network mounts (especially if you set `_netdev` in the options) automatically get `After=network-online.target` and `Wants=network-online.target`.  Pulling in `network-online.target` is supposed to do the job.  E.g. on my computer, `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` has been enabled, by which it means it is started when (well, before) `network-online.target` is started...

Comment: This is Fedora, and the unit is enabled by systemd.preset.  However this Fedora setup also appears stupidly fragile. If NetworkManager is used (enabled), I don't see why it wouldn't automatically enable the corresponding wait-online service, using an `Also=` in the `[Install]` section of NetworkManager.service

Comment: There was a similar bug in the systemd-networkd units which was fixed in v234: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/9e49656037717b96c06b1f1507a41550bdb2c795